# Asynchronous programming in C#.Net without using thread

Tags: c#, .net

In C#.Net, Is it possible to program asynchronously without using thread like Node.js?

Comment: Did you research anything before posting this question? A simple Google search for [`c# asynchronous`](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+asynchronous) yields over 850,000 results, the first of which will lead you directly to `async`/`await`. Even prior to .NET 4.5, the many of the BCL classes support async operations via callbacks.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart thaks for the answer, I know that we can await for a method that implements awaitable. My question was, does awatable method need a different thread or it can run in main thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer yes that is possible using async and await.

Start here for learning this technology : http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html

Comment: Thanks Philip. I know that we can await for a method that implements awaitable. My question was, does awatable method need a different thread or it can run in main thread?

Comment: This post is absolutely awesome (and goes into more detail as to how pure async operations don't block *any threads at all*): http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html